# Positioning guides between pixels in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides, pixel-grid

Is it possible to create a guide between two pixels?
I know that I can create a shape and position freely (independent of the pixel grid), and then I can transform that shape into guides, and in that case the guides would be EXACTLY where I want them.

But I was wondering if there was an option that would allow me to position the default horizontal/vertical guidelines without alignment to the grid?

Comment: I'm just bringing up the rules (cmd+r) and then drag the guides from them

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there are two situations when new guides made by dragging from the rulers will snap to the pixel grid:

1. Pixel Preview is turned on (View → Pixel Preview)
2. "Align New Objects to Pixel Grid" is checked in the Transform panel menu

[image: Align New Object to Pixel Grid]

So, to stop your new guides snapping to the pixel grid: turn off pixel preview and uncheck "Align New Objects to Pixel Grid" in the Transform panel menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to grab the guide and manually enter it's position as something like 12.5px for the x-coordinate. If it won't let you, I suppose that's the story.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `View` → `Snap to Point` turn on, and `View` → `Snap to Grid` turn off, you can snap guides to objects.

You’ll just need to get the position you want with an object first. This can be done by drawing something on the pixel grid, then pressing `A` and `Enter` to open the Move window, where you can type in an exact offset (or choose `Object` → `Transform` → `Move`).

[image: Adobe Illustrator snapping guides to objects]